# How can I modify my read function in my FIFO implementation of a cache simulator

Tags: c, caching, cpu-architecture, simulator

I have a cache simulator which implements a FIFO method of caching, here are my struct variables for reference:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define DRAM_SIZE 1048576

typedef struct cb_struct {
    unsigned char data[16]; // One cache block is 16 bytes.
    u_int32_t tag;
    u_int32_t timeStamp;   /// This is used to determine what to evict. You can update the timestamp using cycles.
}cacheBlock;


typedef struct access {
    int readWrite; // 0 for read, 1 for write
    u_int32_t address;
    u_int32_t data; // If this is a read access, value here is 0
}cacheAccess;

// This is our dummy DRAM. You can initialize this in anyway you want to test.
unsigned char * DRAM; 

cacheBlock L1_cache[2][2]; // Our 2-way, 64 byte cache
cacheBlock L2_cache[4][4]; // Our 4-way, 256 byte cache

// Trace points to a series of cache accesses.
FILE *trace;

long cycles;

void init_DRAM();


// This function print the content of the cache in the following format for an N-way cache with M Sets
// Set 0   : CB1 | CB2 | CB 3 | ... | CB N
// Set 1   : CB1 | CB2 | CB 3 | ... | CB N
// ...
// Set M-1 : CB1 | CB2 | CB 3 | ... | CB N
```

and here is my implementation of the `read` function, which is meant to read the cache in FIFO method:

```
//Here is the read function I'm talking about. 
u_int32_t read_fifo(u_int32_t address)
{
    u_int32_t setID = getL1SetID(address);
    u_int32_t tag = getL1Tag(address);
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (L1_cache[setID][i].tag == tag) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (index != -1) {
        return L1_cache[setID][index].data[address & 0xF];
    }
    u_int32_t l2SetID = getL2SetID(address);
    tag = getL2Tag(address);
    index = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (L2_cache[l2SetID][i].tag == tag) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (index != -1) {
        cacheBlock newBlock;
        newBlock.tag = tag;
        memcpy(newBlock.data, L2_cache[l2SetID][index].data, 16);
        cacheBlock temp = L1_cache[setID][0];
        if (temp.tag == L1_cache[setID][1].tag) {
            temp = L1_cache[setID][1];
        }
        L1_cache[setID][0] = newBlock;
        L2_cache[l2SetID][index] = temp;

        return newBlock.data[address & 0xF];
    }
    cacheBlock newBlock;
    newBlock.tag = tag;
    memcpy(newBlock.data, DRAM + (address & 0xFFFFFFF0), 16);

    cacheBlock temp = L2_cache[l2SetID][0];
    if (temp.tag == L2_cache[l2SetID][1].tag) {
        temp = L2_cache[l2SetID][1];
    }
    L2_cache[l2SetID][0] = newBlock;
    memcpy(newBlock.data, DRAM + (address & 0xFFFFFFF0), 16);
    temp = L1_cache[setID][0];
    if (temp.tag == L1_cache[setID][1].tag) {
        temp = L1_cache[setID][1];
    }
    L1_cache[setID][0] = L2_cache[l2SetID][0];
    L2_cache[l2SetID][0] = temp;

    return L1_cache[setID][0].data[address & 0xF];
}



unsigned int getL1SetID(u_int32_t address)
{
    unsigned int setID = (address >> 4) & 1;
    return setID;
}

unsigned int getL1Tag(u_int32_t address)
{
    unsigned int tag = address >> 5;
    return tag;
}

unsigned int getL2SetID(u_int32_t address)
{
    unsigned int setID = ((address >> 4) & 3);
    return setID;
}

unsigned int getL2Tag(u_int32_t address)
{
    unsigned int output = (address >> 5) & ((1 << 26) - 1);
    return output;
}

int L1lookup(u_int32_t address)
{
    unsigned int setID = getL1SetID(address);
    unsigned int tag = getL1Tag(address);

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        if(L1_cache[setID][i].tag == getL1Tag(address)){
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int L2lookup(u_int32_t address)
{
    unsigned int setID = getL2SetID(address);
    unsigned int tag = getL2Tag(address);

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if(L2_cache[setID][i].tag == getL2Tag(address))
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question to you all is, is there a better way to implement this, given that

> ```
>  The cache has two levels
> • A cache block is 16 bytes.
> • Each address is accessing 1 bytes of data.
> • The L1 cache is a 64 Bytes, 2-way set associative cache.
> • The L2 cache is a 256 Bytes, 4-way set associative cache.
> • The cache is inclusive, which mean that data in L1 cache will also remain in the L2 cache. In other words, the data in L1 is a subset of the data in L2 (This assumption simplify your design)
> ```

I am a newbie to caching and I formed this based on my limited knowledge of caching, so if the design looks ridiculous or out of the ordinary to you, my reasoning is clear. Any suggestions to clear up the code would be greatly helpful to me. Please provide code with explanations alongside too to help me and others understand your response, thank you.

Comment: "Is there a better way to implement this" both very broad and fairly opinion-based.  Supposing that the code presented works correctly (or you think it does, at least), such a question is better suited for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Don't vandalize your question by removing the code.

Answer (score 1):

For a two-way set associative cache, 1 bit of state will tell us which entry is least recent (or first in if that's what you're doing), and hence also which entry is most recent.  This single bit of state belongs at the level of the whole cache line set rather than part of either of the two ways.

Same is true for four-way set associative cache, but takes more than 1 bit.  I think that requires 2 or 3 bits (can be looked up) and there's simple algorithms that advance the way indicator on a hit.

---

If it were me, I would separate the searching of the L1 and L2 caches, since having a hit/miss in each should have different behaviors.

Search L1; if found, return the data.

Search L2; if found, we know it is in L2 but not L1; So, evict one way of that line from L1 and copy from L2 to L1, now it is in L1, so return the data as per found in L1.

If not found in either, then perform L2 cache miss: evict one way of that line in L2 and read from memory, then proceed as per found in L2 (evict one way from L1 and copy from L2 to L1 and return as per found in L1).

---

As far as FIFO, that seems like an odd choice.  Least recently used is more common and almost certainly more effective.

Also, you're always choosing way 0 to evict rather than using your timestamps — as a result, the other ways will go unutilized forever!

In case of miss for both L1 and L2, you're doing `u_int32_t l2SetID = getL2SetID(address);` twice.

---

Does this code actually work?

```
// this code runs whether found in L1 or L2,
// but is written as if positively found in L1
if (index != -1) { 
    return L1_cache[setID][index].data[address & 0xF];
}
```

Seems to me that return statement should use the `cache` variable as due to the conflation of L1 and L2 searches, it could have be found in either L1 or L2 — but if found in L2, there's no promotion of data from L2 to L1 as we would expect.

The point being that the L2 tends to be larger, and thus also slower (size costs speed).  So a miss in L1 should cause a refill in L1 (whether also an L2 hit or miss) to speed subsequent access of the same or nearby addresses by way of now being L1 hits.

---

There's no dirty bits, nor valid bits in the ways.

Comment: *at the level of the cache line rather than part of either of the two ways.* - Pretty sure you mean "at the level of the **set**".  Each way is a cache line.  But yes, this 1-bit or 2-bit counter to the next eviction position was discussed in comments on an earlier question from the OP about an earlier version of the same code (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75945082/how-can-i-finish-implementing-my-write-function-to-simulate-a-write-request-on-a#comment133952547_75945082), which they've since deleted instead of editing with their updated attempt.

Comment: Also, in comments there they discussed using tag=0xFFFFFFFF as a code for "invalid". 
 It can't match `addr >> 5`, so it's effectively using one extra tag bit as the valid/invalid bit.  But reposts of their question keep failing to include design notes like that.  (Both levels are write-through so dirty bits aren't needed.)

Comment: But perhaps they don't need any valid/invalid bits when there aren't any other agents in the system, only the CPU can access RAM.  But hrm, the initial state of having all lines alias (tag=0) could be a problem: after a write that hits on tag==0, there are conflicting lines in the cache, all with the same tag but different data.  If later writes or reads start searching for tag matches in the "wrong" place, they'll hit on a different copy of the `tag == 0` line in that set.  So I don't think we can quite get away with just using the zero-init state for the static storage.

Comment: I agree that hardware doesn't really need valid bits when it can otherwise be determined if properly initialized, however, I believe that most coursework will include them rather than making assumptions about or getting into requirements of the address space and/or operating system.

Comment: @ErikEidt I've edited my response that conforms to what you suggested in your response, I just want to ask that is the edited code better in your opinion, and are there any fixes needed. when I run it on my computer, there are no compilation errors, so I have no clue whether I'm right or not, so just wanna ask and see if that is better?